# Sorry the application has stopped unexpectedly android

Tags: android

Can someone please tell me how to fix my problem?  I'm building my first android app and below  is the error codes I get when application is launched in Emulator.

Thank you

```
04-12 21:07:03.480: D/AndroidRuntime(327): Shutting down VM
04-12 21:07:03.480: W/dalvikvm(327): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception(group=0x40015560)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{obd.gss.namespace/obd.gss.namespace.activity.Gssobdreadermainactivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: obd.gss.namespace.activity.Gssobdreadermainactivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/obd.gss.namespace-1.apk]
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: obd.gss.namespace.activity.Gssobdreadermainactivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/obd.gss.namespace-1.apk]
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
04-12 21:07:03.580: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  ... 11 more
```

Here are the contents of my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<application
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".Activity.Gssobdreadermainactivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.Gssobdreaderconfigactivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.Gssobdreadercommandactivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <service android:name="io.GssobdReaderService"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your problem is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: obd.gss.namespace.activity.Gssobdreadermainactivity
```

Did you forget to add your Activity to your manifest?

Your Manifest should look something like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="obd.gss.namespace"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
 <!-- permissions and other stuff here -->
<application
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".activity.Gssobdreadermainactivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<!--more activities and services here -->
</application>
</manifest>
```

Note that the combination of the manifest tag's package attribute and the activity tag's name attribute should be exactly the same as the fully qualified name of your class. Using my above example, you would wind up with:

```
obd.gss.namespace.activity.Gssobdreadermainactivity
```

Comment: I don't believe this is a manifest problem, the Android logs usually say 'Did you forget to add the Activity to AndroidManifest.xml?' in that case.

Comment: Your manifest file was created when you started your project.  If you are using Eclipse, it will show up as AndroidManifest.xml at the top level of your project directory.  This explains how to add your Activity to your manifest: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Declaring

Comment: I mean how do I add mainfest to here??

Comment: @CarlosHernandez It looks like the problem is that you have the wrong android:name in your activity. It probably should be .activity.Gssobdreadermainactivity, but I can't say for sure without seeing your manifest tag.  See the edit I made to my answer.  In the future, you should edit your original question and add in more content instead of doing it as an answer.

Comment: @elevine nm, they deleted my post

Comment: @CarlosHernandez I know, but you should have edited your question and added it there.  I did it for your anyway.  You did not provide the  <manifest> tag.  If its missing then you need to add it. I took a guess as to what you had for your package attribute's value.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, particularly with newly imported projects. The closest thing to a solution I've found is to make sure the .classpath file is writable, restart Eclipse(or whichever IDE you use), refresh the project, clean and build the project and try again. This doesn't always fix it, but doing it a couple times usually makes the error go away for me. The essence of the error is that the Android OS can't find the Activity, although it does know that the Activity should exist and is trying to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

What does your source tree look like?  You probably need to remove the .activity. and .Activity. prefixes from your applications fully quallified class name.  Unless, of course, you have an "activity" and an "Activity" folder in your source tree (=